# Edit past App Store update messages

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, software-distribution

I'm wondering if one is allowed to edit the 'What's New' info for past versions of the app? Although not on the surface, users can still access these past update messages via the 'Version History' tab on the app page in the App Store.

Many Thanks,

Edward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, iTunesConnect > My Apps > App Store > App Information only allows editing the Ready for Sale (current) and Prepare for Submission (next).

For older versions under iTunesConnect > My Apps > Activity > App Store Versions there is only single line activity information with a date.

Answer (score 0):

No,we can update only when prepare for submission or in waiting for review state.